# Sprite disappears on android

Tags: android, unity

I am programming a game in 2D for android and pc/mac. The sprite is the same and it's visible on the pc/mac. But once I use android and move the sprite, it disappears. The code is this: what could be the reason?

This is what it looks like:

[image: example]

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
  float MitteX = Screen.width - 80;
  float MitteY = 80;
  float x = Input.touches[0].position.x - MitteX;
  float y = Input.touches[0].position.y - MitteY;
  if (Input.touches[0].position.x > Screen.width/2)
  {
    float r = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(y, 2)) / 100;
    if (r > 0.5f)
    {
      r = 1.5F;
      KameraAbstand = 50;
    }
    else
      KameraAbstand = 20;

    anim.SetFloat("Geschwindigkeit", r);
    Vector2 n = new Vector2(x, y).normalized;
    if (!anim.GetBool("istTot"))
    {
      rb.velocity = n * maxGeschwindigkeit;
      rb.transform.forward = n;
      //rb.transform.Rotate(0, 0, phi - phiv);
      neu.text = r + "\n" + n.x + " " + n.y;
      if (rb.transform.forward.x < 0)
      {
        Vector3 skalJetzt = transform.localScale;
        skalJetzt.y = -1;
        transform.localScale = skalJetzt;
      }
      else
      {
        Vector3 skalJetzt = transform.localScale;
        skalJetzt.y = 1;
        transform.localScale = skalJetzt;
      }
    }
  }
#else
  float ho = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  float ve = 0;
  if (umdrehen)
    ve = -Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
  else
    ve = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
  {
    ve *= 1.5F;
    KameraAbstand = 50;
  }
  else
  {
    KameraAbstand = 20;
  }

  anim.SetFloat("Geschwindigkeit", Mathf.Abs(ve));
  if (!anim.GetBool("istTot"))
  {
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(
      ve * maxGeschwindigkeit * transform.right.x, 
      ve * maxGeschwindigkeit * transform.right.y);

    rb.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, ho);
  }
  if (transform.right.x < 0)
  {
    Vector3 skalJetzt = transform.localScale;
    skalJetzt.y = -1;
    transform.localScale = skalJetzt;
  }
  else
  {
    Vector3 skalJetzt = transform.localScale;
    skalJetzt.y = 1;
    transform.localScale = skalJetzt;
  }
#endif
```

Comment: How big is the sprite? And the sprite sheet?

Comment: What is a sprite sheet?

Comment: That's a lengthy answer... If you don't know what it is, you probably are using a single sprite as the sprite sheet, so just the dimensions of the sprite should be sufficient.

Comment: Okay, one is 864 x 304, one is 372 x 324, one is 180 x 108, one is 468 x 60. Some are multiple, some are single.

Comment: The multiple sprites is where sprite sheets come into play (A sprite sheet is basically a single image divided into many sprites). I was asking because Android has a max size smaller than a desktop, I think 2096x2096 pixels or something like that, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Hmmm...

Comment: Why are you using Android specific code? You probably shouldn't use that unless you have a really specific purpose...

Comment: This is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/CPYoju7.gif

Answer (score -1):

There are a few bugs involved with negative scaling in Unity 5 so my best bet on the issue on first sight would be this line of code:

```
Vector3 skalJetzt = transform.localScale;
skalJetzt.y = -1;
transform.localScale = skalJetzt;
```

Instead of setting the localscale to -1 you could try to use transform.rotate() to set up your sprite facing the right direction.

Had similar problems before in the past so I hope this may help you out.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem.